# Cookies are not saving in browser using axios but they are saved in Insomnia

Tags: cookies, http-headers, session-cookies, httpcookie, cookie-httponly

I have an application that uses Reactjs as the client and node express as the server-side.
I am sending cooking in the header at the server, the cookies are shown at the browser but they are not been saved but they are saved I use Insomnia
I have read many questions and answers regarding this but didn't actually solve the issue.
below is my setup

#### client side  sample code

```js
 export const BusinessLogin = (header,account) => axios.post(`${businessURI}/login`, account, header) // 

export const LoginBusiness = (account) => async (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
        headers :{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
         credentials: "include",
         withCredentials: true
    }
    try {
        const  data  = await api.BusinessLogin(config,account)
        console.log(data)
        dispatch({type:LOGIN_BUSINESS, payload: data })
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error.message)
    }

}
```

#### Server-side index file

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin:'http://localhost:3000/',
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //client is hosted at '127.0.0.1:3000'
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '127.0.0.1:3000');
    //  res.header('XMLHTTPRequest','http://127.0.0.1:3000/')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-pagination, Content-Length');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

  import business from './routes/business.js';
  app.use('/buss',  business)

// Libraries 
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
```

#### Server-side router file

```js
  // different libries tried 
 import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
 import cookie from 'cookie'

export const Login = async (req, res) => {
      
    const {email, password} = req.body; 
    const new_account = req.body; 
    const {cookies} = req
   //  console.log("cookies",req.sessionStore)
     console.log("cookies",req.cookies)
    //  console.log(req)
     const  test_cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '');
     console.log(test_cookies)
 
    //  console.log( req)
    if(!email || !password ) return res.status(400).json('fill all field') 
    
    try {
        await CreateBusiness.findOne({email})
        .then(account => {
            
            if(!account) return res.status(400).json({msg:"The email or password you enter does not match account"})
            //Validate password with  exiting password 
            bcrypt.compare(password, account.password) 
              .then(isMatch => {
             
                  if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({msg: "invalid credentials "})
              //user match, 
              jwt.sign(
                { id: account._id },
                Jwt_secret,
                { expiresIn: 3600 }, //last for hour
                (error, token) => {
                    if(error) throw error;
                    
                    const cookies = {
                        maxAge: 3600,
                        httpOnly: false,
                        sameSite:false,
                        // secure: true // activate during deployment
                    }
                    // trying different methods of setting cookis
                     res.cookie('accessToken', '474949',cookies)
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
                    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('name', 'just tetsing the cooki', {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
                      }));
                    res.status(201).cookie('access_token', 'Bearer ' + token, cookies)
                    res.json({
                        token,
                        account, 
                    })
                    // res.status(200).json(res)
                }
            )
       
        })
    })
   
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(209).json({message: error.message})

    }
   
}
```

#### Other things I have tried

After reading similar questions some suggest to set  `//axios.defaults.withCredentials = true,` but each time did I will have a cors error even though I have made the cors configurations as shown, although I have added `withCredentials: true` in the configuration.
I have also used this [cors extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) but still, the cookies are not saving on the browser.

What do you think is causing them not to save and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Technically,  the setup above is correct,  the main reason why the cookie was not saving in the browser was that my Server was running at  http://localhost:7000/  while my frontend was  http://127.0.0.1:3000/  which makes them different domain. The fix this , i just made my frontend to run  at http://localhost:3000/  and the issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

When setting cookies on the server set sameSite to 'lax'. If it is set to 'none' it will not work unless the cookie also has the 'secure' attribute. This is enforced by the browser.

Insmonia and other REST clients don't care about this.

[**Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)

```
res.cookie('accessToken', foo, {
    maxAge: 3600,
    sameSite: "lax",
    path: "/",
  });
```

Also, make sure you are passing `credentials: 'include'` when making the fetch request, which, I can see you are doing.